# IntelliJ Git checkout in one instance corrupts opened project in another instance

Tags: git, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, workspace

I use IntelliJ Idea 18 + Git in our project.

I have cloned myproject into locations like `C:\workspaces\myproject1` and `C:\workspaces\myproject2`

If I open 2 instances of IntelliJ: one pointing to `myproject1` and another into `myProject2` then if I start using myproject1 and switch branches in that IntelliJ IDEA... it sorts of corrupts the myproject2 as well.

Why is it happening? I just want to have 2 copies of the repo working at the same time in the machine so that I can usually work on my branch and can also peer review another branch from the same repo in another IntelliJ project. But changing one branch in IntelliJ (`myproject1`) also impacts the `myproject2`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you should open `myproject1` and `myproject2` in completely different IntelliJ instances. 
From your description, it looks like they are "overlapping" somewhere and it could be due to:

1. You have opened your projects by choosing `C:\workspaces\`
2. You have opened the same project by mistake

Comment: I open in 2 instances .One I open C:\workspaces\myproject1-pom.xml and another from C:\workspaces\myproject2-pomxml